# Eclipse - Force.com IDE Refresh Wiping Local Files

Tags: force.com, ide, eclipse

I'm currently using Mars (4.5) for Eclipse, and downloaded the Force.com plugin as per the instructions here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation

When I create a force.com proect, it pulls the information in correctly, however whenever I refresh it wipes the file and says the component has nothing in it aside from the xml version and the soap line.

We are using perforce for our versioning (perforce is working exactly as intended), and the issue I'm encountering is that when I refresh from my sandbox and do a diff, it says my sandbox has no contents. Thought it was a connection issue, but Eclipse (as stated above) is able to build the project initially, but after that any update wipes the local file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
   <Package xmlns="soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">; 
      <types>
         <members>Account</members> 
         <name>CustomObject</name> 
      </types> 
   <version>36.0</version>
  </Package>
```

Comment: welcome to SE. Can you post your package.xml from project with this question

Comment: Hi Himanshy, I apologize for the delayed response, been out for a bit. I tested this with various objects/layouts etc, but as an example here is the XML of my force.com project: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Account</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>36.0</version>
</Package>

After Refresh From Server I get this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"/>

Comment: your xml looking fine. can you put screenshot as well from your eclipse. project explorer.

Comment: I created a test object in my sandbox (I have tested this in multiple sandboxes) XML Package: http://i.imgur.com/9GJPWvk.png Object XML Full: http://i.imgur.com/lIuAs8F.png And then on refresh: http://i.imgur.com/TBjz93I.png